# How to connect MySQL Workbench to Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, database, ssh, mysql-workbench, mysqladministrator

I am accessing the Amazon RDS (MySQL) from Putty. MySQL Workbench works through SSH commandline only, but I would like to access the cloud MySQL host database directly from MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In the MySQL forums is a posting that links to various sources for connecting MySQL Workbench to online resources: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,252640,252640#msg-252640. The essential steps for Amazon RDS are on this page: https://thoughtsandideas.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/monitoring-and-managing-amazon-rds-databases-using-mysql-workbench/

Step 3) Fill in the values as described below which illustrated in Figure 4.

- Connection Name – Provide a name to identify your connection
  Connection Method – Select Standard TCP/IP over SSH from the drop
  down list instead of Standard(TCP/IP). Then on the appearing two tabbed pane, fill the following values found under Parameters tab.
- SSH Hostname – Provide the Public DNS of the Amazon EC2 instace
  (refer Figure 3) which will be used as the intermediate server
  instance used to create the connection with the DB instance.
- SSH Username – Provide the user of the Amazon EC2 instance (refer Figure 3) which will be used as the intermediate server instance used to create the connection with the DB instance.
- SSH Key File – Provide the Private Key (xxx.pem) used to connect
  Amazon EC2 instace via SSH
- MySQL Hostname – Provide the Endpoint of the DB instance created in Amazon RDS(refer Figure 5).
- Username – Provide the Master Username of the DB instance created in Amazon RDS(refer Figure 5).
- Password – Click on Store in Keychain.. button and type the password provided while creating the DB instance in Amazon RDS.

Comment: Anil, if an answer was helpful please accept it by clicking the check mark left to it. You can even upvote for additional points if you feel the answer deserves it.

Comment: Also make sure you use a PEM key and not a PPK key

Comment: why is it necessary to use TCP/IP over ssh?

Comment: Please ask follow up questions as own questions.

Comment: This is excellent

Answer (score 64):

This solution worked for me: Add your IP to the Security Group rules as follows. Assuming you have logged into AWS:

1. Go to RDS -> Databases -> Select your database

[image]

2. Make sure the **Public Accessibility** value is **Yes**
   [image]
3. Check your IP address using http://checkip.amazonaws.com/. If it is not added to the Security Rule Groups, you should add it. **this step is crucial**

3.1. Click on the rule name. This will open up a new tab, then click in the name of the rule.

[image]

3.2. Click on **Edit inbound rules**

[image]

3.3. Click on Add new rule, and add a rule with the following values:

**Type:** MYSQL/Aurora.

**Protocol:** TCP (default)

**Port range:** 3306 (default)

**Source:** My IP -> This will be the IP Address you got at http://checkip.amazonaws.com/.

[image]

4. Fill information in MySQL Workbench

[image]

**Hostname**: Use the value you have for Endpoint at Connectivity and Security

**Port**: Use the value you have for Port at Connectivity and Security, by default it is 3306.

**Username**: Use the value you have for master username at Configuration

**Password**: Use the value you set when you created the database instance.

If you forgot the password, you can change it by clicking on Modify in your database instance or if you're using AWS Elastic Beanstalk or so you can SSH into the instance and run the command

```
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/bin/get-config environment
```

and you'll find that information in it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Worked great. Thanks for that

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: I have followed that but still getting "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 54" in mysqlworkbench.

Comment: I followed all the steps but I was still getting error message "Unable to connect to <host>". Later I realized, my system was connected to my organization's VPN. I disconnected the VPN on my system > visited site "http://checkip.amazonaws.com/" again> this time my IP was different > I provided this IP in this answers step "inbound rule" , "source" . After this, I was able to connect from MySQL Workbench

Comment: my ip  changing . what  value should i put when adding new rules . any help ?

Comment: Worked well, thank you so much saved life.

Comment: Does the Public Accessibility have to be yes to connect this way? What if I want to connect but not have it publicly accessible?

Comment: Also make sure to have a public subnet group

Comment: It was also required for me to reassociate the VPC subnet groups to the route table that had the routing for the internet gateway.

Answer (score 2):

- In the MySQL Workbench Click on Setup new Connection,
- Give the Connection name and Select the Connection method as Standard TCP/IP,
- Enter the host name from RDS end point and port as 3306,
- Enter Mysql user name and password as given in RDS instance creation,
- Then test the connection and click ok.

[image: Test MySQL Connection]

Comment: if using AWS documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/tutorials/create-mysql-db/) in Step 3b the UI has changed so the endpoint info is not there as they instructed.

to find: services > RDS > Instances > click the instance name link > search = endpoint. you will see it under "Connect" module

Answer (score 0):

Very helpful , was able to make the connection was missing critical part

3.3. Click on Add new rule, and add a rule with the following values:

Type: MYSQL/Aurora.

Protocol: TCP (default)

Port range: 3306 (default)

Source: My IP -> This will be the IP Address you got at http://checkip.amazonaws.com/.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a DB and you chose **create VPC security group** then the inbound rule will already be set up with your IP address so no need to do that step.

Also, your password that you enter must be a strong password and adhering to the following rules:

- contain upper case characters
- contain lower case characters
- be atleast 8 characters
- contains numbers
- contain symbol (excluding @, ', ", , /)

Only after I entered a strong password did my connection work.