# How to connect MySQL Work bench to Amazon RDS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mysql-workbench, amazon-rds

I have followed [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/TUT_WebAppWithRDS.html) link to create an Amazon RDS. I am very new to RDS.

Anyway, now I can't connect to the RDS using **MySQL Workbench**. Eventhough I tried to connect via the EC2 instance created at the end of tutorial, still I have no progress. How can I do this?

If this way is pretty hard, please advice me about a way where I can create a RDS which can be connected via MySQL Workbench and can be used via a web app hosted in EC2. Your answer should be suitable for production environment.

Comment: Why haven't you searched the web first for an answer? Alone here on SO I see about 10 questions (+ answers) regarding MySQL Workbench connecting to Amazon RDS. Also, when you have trouble with a connection then tell us what exactly did you try (exact setttings etc.).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect MySQL Workbench to Amazon RDS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429493/how-to-connect-mysql-workbench-to-amazon-rds)