# How To Connect MySQL Workbench to Amazon RDS running in VPC

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

So, I have done this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/TUT_WebAppWithRDS.html from step 1-3 and it works fine.

For now I do `INSERT`/`SELECT` `Query` my `Amazon RDS Database` by changing the `Sample.PHP` from [last step of tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_Tutorials.WebServerDB.CreateWebServer.html). And it is kinda annoying.

So, I think I will use `MySQL Workbench` to make it easier and tried to [Connect MySQL Workbench to Amazon RDS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60976755/12958413) . But it won't connect

I did `telnet <RDS endpoint> <port number>` and it could not open connection too.

After some research, (CMIIW) From what I learn, this tutorial private the `RDS Instance` only can be accessed by the `EC2 Instance`.

My Question: how can I connect `MySQL Workbench` / anything that make me easier to do Database Query with that Tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

To access using MySQL Workbench from your own PC, you should ensure the database has a security group that allows access from your network (or specific IP address) to port 3306/tcp (if you're using the default), *AND* you need to make the DB instance publicly accessible by setting is as YES in the connectivity options of the instance.